# How do I install a Bluetooth mouse with Boot Camp (Win10)?

Tags: bootcamp, windows, bluetooth, mouse

I'm trying to add a Bluetooth mouse to my Apple Macbook using Win10 on a BootCamp partition.

--I purchased the Logitech M557 Bluetooth mouse as it seemed to have a great record for robust installation.
--Mouse works great on my MacBook laptop with MacOS.
--Mouse works great on my HP desktop machine loaded with Windows 10.

I can NOT get the bluetooth system to successfully mate with the same mouse with Bootcamp / Windows 10 on the very same Macbook laptop.  I suspect that I need custom Windows bluetooth drivers for Bootcamp (which I presume should come from the Apple BootCamp folks...)

Via windows device manager, I've removed, added, updated drivers numerous times, all to no avail.  Now, the add bluetooth system sees the mouse, attempts to add it, but fails consistently at:

**Bluetooth Mouse M557. Try connecting your device again.**

I have no idea what is generating that code, but no matter what I try I get no where.

Anybody been here before?  Are there special Bluetooth drivers for Bootcamp / Windows?

Current driver info (as displayed in Bootcamp Windows)

```
Device Manager shows four BlueTooth Devices:
Bluetooth Radio
Microsoft Bluetooth Enumerator
Microsoft Bluetooth LE Enumerator
Microsoft Bluetooth Protocol Support Driver

Bluetooth Radio:
    Device Type: Bluetooth
    Manufacturer: Microsoft
    Location: Location 4097 (Serial HCI Bus - Bluetooth Function)
    Driver Files:   C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\BthMini.SYS     File Version: 10.0.16299.15
            C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\bthport.sys     File Version: 10.0.16299.15
Microsoft Bluetooth Enumerator
    Device Type: Bluetooth
    Manufacturer: Microsoft
    Location: Location 4097
    Driver Files:   C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\bthenum.sys     File Version: 10.0.16299.15             
Microsoft Bluetooth LE Enumerator
    Device Type: Bluetooth
    Manufacturer: Microsoft
    Location: Location 4097
    Driver Files:   C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\Microsoft.Bluetooth.Legacy.LEEnumerator.sys     File Version: 10.0.16299.15             
Microsoft Bluetooth Protocol Support Driver:
    Device Type: Bluetooth
    Manufacturer: Microsoft
    Location: Location 4097 
    Driver Files:   C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\bthl2cap.sys        File Version: 10.0.16299.15
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this response in [a different forum.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/bluetooth-mouse-paired-connected-but-not-works-in/710e8230-8e49-46ab-b903-fb4e5d366532)

> OK this is how I fixed my problem in Windows 10 Boot Camp on MacBook Pro 2016. Apple Magic Mouse recognized, paired but kept disconnecting almost immediately if it connected at all. The problem was related to the Power Management under Bluetooth Radio, Properties in Device Manager. I had to uncheck 'Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power'.  This has worked for me I'm relieved to say :)

Totally nailed it.

- Click on start button.
- In the search box type devmgmt.msc and then press enter.
- Click on the Bluetooth Mouse Icon
- Right Click on Bluetooth Radio, Choose Properties.
- Select the PowerManagement Tab
- Uncheck the [] for "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power"
- Reboot.
- Success!

Answer (score 2):

I solved my Bluetooth Mice issue in Windows 10 Boot Camp as of Feb 2021 with latest macOS Big Sur update by following:

1. Update macOS and follow steps here to install Windows Support Software: https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204923
2. Update Windows. Went to Settings, Device Manager, Bluetooth and update driver for all Bluetooth radio and everything. Restart.
3. I followed steps: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/windows-10-missing-bluetooth-power-management-tab/62e63e7d-9954-4898-b2a3-44fed70421c5?page=2

   > First, go to Device Manager > Human Interface Devices.
   >
   > 1. Click on the "Bluetooth Low Energy GAT compliant HID device" and there's a power management tab in it. Disable/un-tick the "allow the computer to turn off this device to save power".
   > 2. Click on "I2C HID Device" and there's a power management tab in it. Disable/un-tick the "allow the computer to turn off this device to save power".

   Didn't work. Can't find Power Management Tab in Bluetooth radio?
4. Looked through every single line in Windows Device Manager, and disable/untick everything that power management tab > "allow the computer to turn off this device to save power". " - Not sure of negative effects.
5. Shut down MacBook and waited ten minutes. Boot up straight into Windows.
6. Turned off Bluetooth and turned on. Paired Logitech G604 mice and it is working now.
7. I even bought the Logitech unifying receiver which I may not need now. Initially I deduce, the unifying receiver will not help as my Apple Mice did not work via Bluetooth in Windows Boot Camp.
8. The Logitech Mice have been working for the past hour and I will monitor.

Answer (score 1):

Try to update your Bluetooth drivers through Intel's website. They do have drivers that you can download.

Comment: Tried this in ten different ways, (install, remove, etc...) all with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

This apple thread is another option using apple´s own drivers

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250233849