# Bluetooth Radio Driver reverts to windows driver when booting into windows from Macbook Pro

Tags: windows, bootcamp, bluetooth, driver

I just booted into Windows 10 on my 2019 MBP. I have had this partition for around one year, since I bought the computer. Upon booting into Windows 10, I noticed that my wireless mouse (logitech) will not connect to my windows partition, but does on my Mac OS. Upon further investigation, my bluetooth driver is gone.

I booted back into Mac OS, redownloaded the bootcamp/Windows support software on a USB drive, booted back into Windows 10, and repaired the bootcamp partition. Upon repairing the partition, the mouse connects and the bluetooth driver and corresponding icon shows up in my lower right corner of my screen. Everything works as normal. The problem is, when I restart my computer and boot back into Windows 10 again, bluetooth does not work again.

Upon opening device manager, I see the bluetooth symbol, but there is an error icon next to the bluetooth radio symbol. [image: Bluetooth Radio Error]

I'm not sure what is going on here. Perhaps the Windows partition is trying to update the driver with it's own driver on top of the apple driver? Unsure of what to do next.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309962/how-do-i-install-a-bluetooth-mouse-with-boot-camp-win10?rq=1 Have you tried the accepted solution from there?

Comment: @X_841 The question is slightly different, but when trying the accepted solution I get to the point of the “Power Management” tab, but the “Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power” checkbox is greyed out. EDIT: It is greyed out, but is already unchecked.